# How to Apply CSS on HTML to Excel export

Tags: php, html, excel, laravel-5.1

I am trying to export HTML to Excel format using php headers, but CSS styling is not applying on elements (while export to excel file), I also try to implement Bootstrap Classes, but no luck

**Note**: while applying bootstrap classes, I included the bootstrap.css in my html

Is there any way available to apply CSS?

**Headers using**

```
    header('Content-type: application/excel');        
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$filename\"");
```

**Sample HTML elements**

```
<table width="100%" border="1" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="9" style="font-weight: bold; font-size: 16px; text-align: center;"><h2>Push Notification </h2></td>
        </tr>
        <tr><td colspan="9"></td></tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
        <tr class="heading">
            <th colspan="2" ></th>
            <th style="width:2% !important">S.no</th>
            <th style="width:10% !important">Date</th>
            <th style="width:10% !important">App</th>
            <th style="width:20%">Category</th>
            <th colspan="2" style="width:50%">Message</th>
        </tr>

        @if($push_notifications->count() > 0)
            <?php $counter = 1; ?>
            @foreach($push_notifications as $notification)
                <tr @if(($counter %2) ==1) bcolor="#c9c9c9" @endif>
                    <td colspan="2"></td>
                    <td style="width:2% !important">{!!$counter!!}</td>
                    <td style="width:10% !important">{!!$notification->date!!}</td>
                    <td style="width:10% !important">{!!$notification->notificationAppType->name!!}</td>
                    <td style="width:20%">{!!$notification->notificationCategory->name!!}</td>
                    <td colspan="2" style="width:50%">{!!htmlentities($notification->message, ENT_QUOTES)!!}</td>
                </tr>
                <?php $counter++; ?>
            @endforeach

        @else
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="9">No record available</td>
                </tr>
        @endif
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: try PHPExcel: https://phpexcel.codeplex.com

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Short answer is **no, you can't apply css to excel**.

You can, however, apply some formatting to the text of excel files, but the amount of formatting is limited by the library you use to generate the excel file and to what formatting the excel itself permits.

Comment: can you provide the list of style formatting which can be applicable on excel?

Comment: this is a totally different question. Please create another one (after you do some searches through the docs of the library you'll use to generate it, of course)