# How to format Excel cell with PHPExcel_Reader_HTML

Tags: php, laravel-5, phpexcel, phpexcelreader

I am using `PHPExcel_Reader_HTML` and passing it my `HTML` to generate excel file, but the problem is that it does not highlight the excel cell color as in the 'HTML' table (see image blow), I am using Laravel5

```
<?php



$content = $title;
$content .= '<table border="1">';
$content .= '<tr>';
foreach($fields as $f )
{
    if($f['download'] =='1') $content .= '<th style="background:#f9f9f9;">'. $f['label'] . '</th>';
}
$content .= '</tr>';

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $content .= '<tr>';
    foreach($fields as $f )
    {
        if($f['download'] =='1'):
            $conn = (isset($f['conn']) ? $f['conn'] : array() );
            $content .= '<td> '. htmlentities(AjaxHelpers::gridFormater($row->$f['field'],$row,$f['attribute'],$conn)) . '</td>';
        endif;
    }
    $content .= '</tr>';
}
$content .= '</table>';
$path = "../storage/app/".time().".html";
file_put_contents($path, $content);

// Read the contents of the file into PHPExcel Reader class
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$content = $reader->load($path);

// Pass to writer and output as needed
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
// Delete temporary file
unlink($path);

// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

// It will be called file.xls
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.' '.date("d/m/Y").'.xlsx"');

// Write file to the browser
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Note: ( My question is different then the questions been asked on stackoverflow, my coding scenario is different then all..)

[image]

Comment: where is image, and you want to apply css in excel, really `different then the questions been asked on stackoverflow`.

Comment: Image added, because i am using `PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter` object and i was applying the code of previously asked questions but it was not working for me (my bad luck )

Comment: Please have a look : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36745376/how-to-apply-css-on-html-to-excel-export

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After going through the `Excel2007` I got solution of my question, I've used the function `getPHPExcel()` of `Excel2007` and Highlight my Excel Cell

```
<?php
function cellColor($objPHPExcel,$cells,$color){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle($cells)->getFill()->applyFromArray(array(
        'type' => PHPExcel_Style_Fill::FILL_SOLID,
        'startcolor' => array(
            'rgb' => $color
        )
    ));
}


$content = $title;
$content .= '<table border="1">';
$content .= '<tr>';
foreach($fields as $f )
{
    if($f['download'] =='1') $content .= '<th style="background:#f9f9f9;">'. $f['label'] . '</th>';
}
$content .= '</tr>';

foreach ($rows as $row)
{
    $content .= '<tr>';
    foreach($fields as $f )
    {
        if($f['download'] =='1'):
            $conn = (isset($f['conn']) ? $f['conn'] : array() );
            $content .= '<td> '. htmlentities(AjaxHelpers::gridFormater($row->$f['field'],$row,$f['attribute'],$conn)) . '</td>';
        endif;
    }
    $content .= '</tr>';
}
$content .= '</table>';
$path = "../storage/app/".time().".html";
file_put_contents($path, $content);

// Read the contents of the file into PHPExcel Reader class
$reader = new PHPExcel_Reader_HTML;
$content = $reader->load($path);

// Pass to writer and output as needed
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($content, 'Excel2007');
$objPHPExcel = $objWriter->getPHPExcel();
$counter=0;
foreach($fields as $f )
{
    if($f['download'] =='1')
        cellColor($objPHPExcel,'A2','F28A8C');
$counter++;
}

// Delete temporary file
unlink($path);

// We'll be outputting an excel file
header('Content-type: application/vnd.ms-excel');

// It will be called file.xls
header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename="'.$title.' '.date("d/m/Y").'.xlsx"');

// Write file to the browser
$objWriter->save('php://output');   
  ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The PHPExcel HTML Reader isn't very sophisticated, and is more concerned with converting the data and the structure of the markup than the styling, particularly as there are many ways to apply styling in html.

What you can do is load the html document, and then use native PHPExcel functionality to set styling before saving it as an xlsx file

Comment: Any helpfull method for `PHPExcel` in this case??

Comment: You mean helpful methods such as [those described in the PHPExcel documentation](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/blob/develop/Documentation/markdown/Overview/08-Recipes.md#styles)?